# How do I get the name of the class the method is defined in?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to create a dynamic implementation of a certain interface using Reflection.
In order to do so I create a new instance of InvocationHandler. The problem is, that within the

```
invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
```

method I need to know the canonical name of the interface the method is defined in.
Any ideas how to get one?

Comment: What if two interfaces have that method?

Comment: Is `method.declaringClass().getCanonicalName()` what you're looking for?

Comment: Uhh.. I must have been bblind not to have noticed this one...